# Issues with header inline Elements

Tags: html, css

How can I allign the `<h2>` element with the `input` field and `button` in one line ? The heading always floats above the search field

```css
#header {
 background-color: grey;
 display: inline-block;
 width: 100%;
 padding: 2px 5px 2px 5px;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <header id="header">
   <h2>MovieDB</h2>
   <input type="text" placeholder="search movie...">
   <button>search</button>
  </header>
</html
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`h2` is a block level element by default, simply make it `inline` or `inline-block`, e.g.

There is no need to apply `inline-block` to the header in this case.

```
#header {
    background-color: grey;
    padding: 2px 5px 2px 5px;
} 

h2, input, button{
  display: inline-block;
}
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/obXrBL

Comment: Thank you for the fast answer.

Answer (score 1):

```css
#header h2{
 background-color: grey;
 display: inline-block;
        width: auto;
 padding: 2px 5px 2px 5px;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <header id="header">
   <h2>MovieDB</h2>
   <input type="text" placeholder="search movie...">
   <button>search</button>
  </header>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

The H1 - H6 elements are `block` elements and are therefore rendered on a new line. To change this, add the CSS to make the H2 an `inline-block` using `display`, i.e;

```css
#header {
 background-color: grey;
 display: inline-block;
 width: 100%;
 padding: 2px 5px 2px 5px;
}

 #header > h2 {
      display: inline-block;
 }
```

```html
<html>
  <header id="header">
   <h2>MovieDB</h2>
   <input type="text" placeholder="search movie...">
   <button>search</button>
  </header>
</html
```

You can find out more [here](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_display.asp)